# Adding using HTML forms and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, math

I'm having some trouble adding numbers taken from a HTML form.  I know this is a really basic question, but nothing seems to work.  I'm trying to add up an user's score in a psychical game, such as Scrabble.  The code is supposed to get the inputted scores and the old scores and add them up, although I haven't added the part to add the numbers yet.  Where and how can I display the added score number in the code?  You can access the web application at: ripdvd.x10.mx/index.php.  Thanks to Michi for already trying to help me with this!

```
<?php
// Get data from HTML form.
$addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];
$oldScore1 = $_POST['oldScore1'];
$oldScore2 = $_POST['oldScore2'];


?>

// Generate HTML form
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Score Add</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="displayNames">   
            <p><?php echo $player1; ?> current score: <?php echo $oldScore1; ?>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <label for="addScore1">Enter your score:</label>
                <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $oldscore1; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </p>

        <p><?php echo $player2; ?> current score: <?php echo $oldScore2; ?>
            <label for="addScore2">Enter your score:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $oldscore2; ?>" />
                <input type=\"submit\"/>
            </form>
             </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you define `$player1` and `$player2` ?

Comment: Please run your code against an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/). There's a few errors you'd surely want to clean up...

Comment: Actually, checking against your url provided i cannot see the <p>-tags breaking the <form> enclosure and the improper `// ` comment in the html... nevermind then i guess ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using cookies to persist the value between post calls:

```
<?php
// Get data from HTML form.
$addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];
$curr1=$_COOKIE["score1"]+$addScore1;
$curr2=$_COOKIE["score2"]+$addScore2;
setcookie("score1", $_COOKIE["score1"]+$addScore1, time()+3600);
setcookie("score2", $_COOKIE["score2"]+$addScore2, time()+3600);


?>

// Generate HTML form
```

```
<body>
    <div id="displayNames">   
        <p><?php echo $player1; ?> current score: <?php echo $oldScore1; ?>
        <form method="post" action="messing.php">
            <label for="addScore1">Enter your score:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $oldscore1; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>

    <p><?php echo $player2; ?> current score: <?php echo $oldScore2; ?>
        <label for="addScore2">Enter your score:</label>
        <input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $oldscore2; ?>" />
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
         </p>
    </div>

    <p>first added score <?php echo $curr1?></p>
    <p>second added score <?php echo $curr2?></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I never would have thought of using cookies to keep the data.  Keep up the good work!  -Max 

Comment: No problem...  If you're serious about persisting scores long term, look into setting up a database.  The php mysqli library makes it pretty easy, and there's tons of good documentation and examples out there

Comment: I looked at using a database, but I'm planing to have tens of users using this at once.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" value="<?php echo $addScore1; ?>" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" value="<?php echo $addScore2; ?>" />
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm looking for.  Your code just makes my form sticky, that is keeping the value inputted.  I'm trying to add numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you can add the following code where you want to display the sum all your score variables:

```
<?php
echo intval($addScore1)+intval($addScore2)+intval($oldScore1)+intval($oldScore2);
?>
```

Comment: It seems like that should work, but it just displays the number I just entered and not the sum total.  It's supposed to be a calculator-like application, adding two or more numbers - one from before, and the new one the user entered.  Hope this clears up any confusion you had.  Thanks,  Max

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Get data from HTML form. 
$addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];
$oldScore1 = $_POST['oldScore1'];
$oldScore2 = $_POST['oldScore2'];

$newScore1 = (int) $oldScore1 + (int) $addScore1;
$newScore2 = (int) $oldScore2 + (int) $addScore2;
?>
<h2>Old Sores</h2>
<p>
<input type="text" value="<?=$oldScore1?>" name="oldScore1">
<input type="text" value="<?=$oldScore2?>" name="oldScore2">
</p>
<h2>New Sores</h2>
<p>
<input type="text" value="<?=$newScore1 ?>" name="newScore1">
<input type="text" value="<?=$newScore1 ?>" name="newScore1">
</p>
```

Is this what you need?

**UPDATE:**
Try this code:
Just tested it works as a calculator :) Hope thats what you need.

```
<?php
// Get data from HTML form. 
$addScore1 = (int) $_POST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = (int) $_POST['addScore2'];

$oldScore1 = (int) $_POST['newScore1'];
$oldScore2 = (int) $_POST['newScore2'];

$newScore1 = (int) $oldScore1 + (int) $addScore1;
$newScore2 = (int) $oldScore2 + (int) $addScore2;

?>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Score Add</title>
    </head>

    <body>  
        <form method="post" action="">
        <h2>Old Scores</h2>
        <p>
        <input type="text" value="<?=$oldScore1?>" name="oldScore1">
        <input type="text" value="<?=$oldScore2?>" name="oldScore2">
        </p>
        <h2>New Scores</h2>
        <p>
        <input type="text" value="<?=$newScore1 ?>" name="newScore1">
        <input type="text" value="<?=$newScore2 ?>" name="newScore2">
        </p>
        <h2>Add Scores</h2>
        <p>
        <input type="text" value="" name="addScore1">
        <input type="text" value="" name="addScore2">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" /> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but no.  Please see my comment on the answer provided by @siluaty.  Thanks,  Max

Comment: Just updated my responce. Take a look and let me know. No cookies required and you can change type from 'text' to 'hidden' on inputs to hide them.